# HTML Greybar stuck at bottom of page

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I cant seem to get rid of the big grey bar at the bottom of the screen, I also want the image to be able to resize depending on the web browser size. All help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="responsive no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
        <!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="responsive no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
        <!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="responsive no-js lt-ie9" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
        <html class="responsive no-js" lang="en-US">
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>24FitClub | Our 24 Fit Club concept is the vehicle to drive you to achieving the best shape of your life</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=100%, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://whoathemes.com/files/pics/favicons/xlander/favicon.ico" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="http://whoathemes.com/files/pics/favicons/xlander/favicon_57.png" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="http://whoathemes.com/files/pics/favicons/xlander/favicon_72.png" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="http://whoathemes.com/files/pics/favicons/xlander/favicon_114.png" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="http://whoathemes.com/files/pics/favicons/xlander/favicon_144.png" />
        <!--[if lt IE 10]>
            <style type="text/css">
            html:not(.is_smallScreen) .wt_animations .wt_animate { visibility:visible;}
            </style>
        <![endif]-->
        <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="24FitClub &raquo; Feed" href="http://thenutritioncoachuk.com/24FitClub/index.php/feed/" />
        <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="24FitClub &raquo; Comments Feed" href="http://thenutritioncoachuk.com/24FitClub/index.php/comments/feed/" />
          <script type="text/javascript">
           window._wpemojiSettings = {"baseUrl":"http:\/\/s.w.org\/images\/core\/emoji\/72x72\/","ext":".png","source":{"concatemoji":"http:\/\/thenutritioncoachuk.com\/24FitClub\/wp-includes\/js\/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.2.2"}};
           !function(a,b,c){function d(a){var c=b.createElement("canvas"),d=c.getContext&&c.getContext("2d");return d&&d.fillText?(d.textBaseline="top",d.font="600 32px Arial","flag"===a?(d.fillText(String.fromCharCode(55356,56812,55356,56807),0,0),c.toDataURL().length>3e3):(d.fillText(String.fromCharCode(55357,56835),0,0),0!==d.getImageData(16,16,1,1).data[0])):!1}function e(a){var c=b.createElement("script");c.src=a,c.type="text/javascript",b.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(c)}var f,g;c.supports={simple:d("simple"),flag:d("flag")},c.DOMReady=!1,c.readyCallback=function(){c.DOMReady=!0},c.supports.simple&&c.supports.flag||(g=function(){c.readyCallback()},b.addEventListener?(b.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",g,!1),a.addEventListener("load",g,!1)):(a.attachEvent("onload",g),b.attachEvent("onreadystatechange",function(){"complete"===b.readyState&&c.readyCallback()})),f=c.source||{},f.concatemoji?e(f.concatemoji):f.wpemoji&&f.twemoji&&(e(f.twemoji),e(f.wpemoji)))}(window,document,window._wpemojiSettings);
          </script>
          <style type="text/css">
        img.wp-smiley,
        img.emoji {
         display: inline !important;
         border: none !important;
         box-shadow: none !important;
         height: 1em !important;
         width: 1em !important;
         margin: 0 .07em !important;
         vertical-align: -0.1em !important;
         background: none !important;
         padding: 0 !important;
        }
        </style>
        <link rel='stylesheet' id='wt-extend-bx-slider-css'  href='http://thenutritioncoachuk.com/24FitClub/wp-content/themes/beautifulhomes/framework/shortcodes/assets/lib/css/jquery.bxslider.css?ver=4.2.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' id='rs-plugin-settings-css'  href='http://thenutritioncoachuk.com/24FitClub/wp-content/plugins/revslider/rs-plugin/css/settings.css?ver=4.6.5' type='text/css' media='all' />
        <style id='rs-plugin-settings-inline-css' type='text/css'>
        .tp-caption a{color:#ff7302;text-shadow:none;-webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease-out;-moz-transition:all 0.2s ease-out;-o-transition:all 0.2s ease-out;-ms-transition:all 0.2s ease-out}.tp-caption a:hover{color:#ffa902}.largeredbtn{font-family:"Raleway",sans-serif;font-weight:900;font-size:16px;line-height:60px;color:#fff !important;text-decoration:none;padding-left:40px;padding-right:80px;padding-top:22px;padding-bottom:22px;background:rgb(234,91,31); background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,rgba(234,91,31,1) 0%,rgba(227,58,12,1) 100%); background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0%,rgba(234,91,31,1)),color-stop(100%,rgba(227,58,12,1))); background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,rgba(234,91,31,1) 0%,rgba(227,58,12,1) 100%); background:-o-linear-gradient(top,rgba(234,91,31,1) 0%,rgba(227,58,12,1) 100%); background:-ms-linear-gradient(top,rgba(234,91,31,1) 0%,rgba(227,58,12,1) 100%); background:linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(234,91,31,1) 0%,rgba(227,58,12,1) 100%); filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ea5b1f',endColorstr='#e33a0c',GradientType=0 )}.largeredbtn:hover{background:rgb(227,58,12); background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,rgba(227,58,12,1) 0%,rgba(234,91,31,1) 100%); background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0%,rgba(227,58,12,1)),color-stop(100%,rgba(234,91,31,1))); background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,rgba(227,58,12,1) 0%,rgba(234,91,31,1) 100%); background:-o-linear-gradient(top,rgba(227,58,12,1) 0%,rgba(234,91,31,1) 100%); background:-ms-linear-gradient(top,rgba(227,58,12,1) 0%,rgba(234,91,31,1) 100%); background:linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(227,58,12,1) 0%,rgba(234,91,31,1) 100%); filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e33a0c',endColorstr='#ea5b1f',GradientType=0 )}.fullrounded img{-webkit-border-radius:400px;-moz-border-radius:400px;border-radius:400px}
        </style>
        <link rel='stylesheet' id='js_composer_front-css'  href='http://thenutritioncoachuk.com/24FitClub/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/css/js_composer.css?ver=4.4.3' type='text/css' media='all' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' id='theme-boostrap-css'  href='http://thenutritioncoachuk.com/24FitClub/wp-content/themes/beautifulhomes/css/bootstrap.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' id='theme-style-css'  href='http://thenutritioncoachuk.com/24FitClub/wp-content/themes/beautifulhomes/css/main.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' id='wt-visual-composer-extensions-front-css'  href='http://thenutritioncoachuk.com/24FitClub/wp-content/themes/beautifulhomes/framework/shortcodes/assets/wt-visual-composer-extensions-front.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' id='theme-awesome-css'  href='http://thenutritioncoachuk.com/24FitClub/wp-content/themes/beautifulhomes/css/font-awesome.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' id='theme-entypo-css'  href='http://thenutritioncoachuk.com/24FitClub/wp-content/themes/beautifulhomes/css/entypo-fontello.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' id='theme-lightbox-css'  href='http://thenutritioncoachuk.com/24FitClub/wp-content/themes/beautifulhomes/css/prettyPhoto.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' id='theme-media-styles-css'  href='http://thenutritioncoachuk.com/24FitClub/wp-content/themes/beautifulhomes/css/main-media.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' id='theme-green-css'  href='http://thenutritioncoachuk.com/24FitClub/wp-content/themes/beautifulhomes/css/skins/green.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' id='theme-skin-css'  href='http://thenutritioncoachuk.com/24FitClub/wp-content/themes/beautifulhomes/cache/skin.css?ver=4.2.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' id='font|Open%20Sans:400,300italic,800italic,800,700italic,700,600italic,600,400italic,300-css'  href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans%3A400%2C300italic%2C800italic%2C800%2C700italic%2C700%2C600italic%2C600%2C400italic%2C300&#038;subset=latin%2Clatin-ext&#038;ver=4.2.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' id='font|Oswald:400,300,700-css'  href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald%3A400%2C300%2C700&#038;subset=latin%2Clatin-ext&#038;ver=4.2.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://thenutritioncoachuk.com/24FitClub/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.2'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://thenutritioncoachuk.com/24FitClub/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://thenutritioncoachuk.com/24FitClub/wp-content/plugins/revslider/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js?ver=4.6.5'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://thenutritioncoachuk.com/24FitClub/wp-content/plugins/revslider/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js?ver=4.6.5'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://thenutritioncoachuk.com/24FitClub/wp-content/themes/beautifulhomes/js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.1.min.js'></script>
        <link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://thenutritioncoachuk.com/24FitClub/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
        <link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://thenutritioncoachuk.com/24FitClub/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" /> 
        <meta name="generator" content="WordPress 4.2.2" />
          <script type="text/javascript">
           jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            // CUSTOM AJAX CONTENT LOADING FUNCTION
            var ajaxRevslider = function(obj) {
            
             // obj.type : Post Type
             // obj.id : ID of Content to Load
             // obj.aspectratio : The Aspect Ratio of the Container / Media
             // obj.selector : The Container Selector where the Content of Ajax will be injected. It is done via the Essential Grid on Return of Content
             
             var content = "";
        
             data = {};
             
             data.action = 'revslider_ajax_call_front';
             data.client_action = 'get_slider_html';
             data.token = '1f054b7c6e';
             data.type = obj.type;
             data.id = obj.id;
             data.aspectratio = obj.aspectratio;
             
             // SYNC AJAX REQUEST
             jQuery.ajax({
              type:"post",
              url:"http://thenutritioncoachuk.com/24FitClub/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
              dataType: 'json',
              data:data,
              async:false,
              success: function(ret, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
               if(ret.success == true)
                content = ret.data;        
              },
              error: function(e) {
               console.log(e);
              }
             });
             
              // FIRST RETURN THE CONTENT WHEN IT IS LOADED !!
              return content;       
            };
            
            // CUSTOM AJAX FUNCTION TO REMOVE THE SLIDER
            var ajaxRemoveRevslider = function(obj) {
             return jQuery(obj.selector+" .rev_slider").revkill();
            };
        
            // EXTEND THE AJAX CONTENT LOADING TYPES WITH TYPE AND FUNCTION
            var extendessential = setInterval(function() {
             if (jQuery.fn.tpessential != undefined) {
              clearInterval(extendessential);
              if(typeof(jQuery.fn.tpessential.defaults) !== 'undefined') {
               jQuery.fn.tpessential.defaults.ajaxTypes.push({type:"revslider",func:ajaxRevslider,killfunc:ajaxRemoveRevslider,openAnimationSpeed:0.3});   
               // type:  Name of the Post to load via Ajax into the Essential Grid Ajax Container
               // func: the Function Name which is Called once the Item with the Post Type has been clicked
               // killfunc: function to kill in case the Ajax Window going to be removed (before Remove function !
               // openAnimationSpeed: how quick the Ajax Content window should be animated (default is 0.3)
              }
             }
            },30);
           });
          </script>
           <style type="text/css">.recentcomments a{display:inline !important;padding:0 !important;margin:0 !important;}</style>
        <meta name="generator" content="Powered by Visual Composer - drag and drop page builder for WordPress."/>
        <!--[if IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://thenutritioncoachuk.com/24FitClub/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/css/vc-ie8.css" media="screen"><![endif]--><style type="text/css">.mc4wp-form input[name="_mc4wp_required_but_not_really"] { display: none !important; }</style><noscript><style> .wpb_animate_when_almost_visible { opacity: 1; }</style></noscript></head>
        <body class="home blog wt_onepage_theme wt_no_space wt_image_bg wpb-js-composer js-comp-ver-4.4.3 vc_responsive" >
        
        <div id="wt_wrapper" class=" fullWidth wt_stickyHeader wt_bcrumbs_enabled wt_nav_top clearfix">
        <div id="wt_page" class="wt_wide">
         <div id="wt_headerWrapper" role="banner" class="clearfix"><header id="wt_header" class="wt_resp_nav_under_767 navbar navbar-fixed-top responsive_nav clearfix" role="banner">     <div class="container">
              
                        <div id="logo" class="navbar-header">
                                                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://thenutritioncoachuk.com/24FitClub/"><img src="http://thenutritioncoachuk.com/24FitClub/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/logo24.png" alt="" /></a>
                             
                        </div>
                      
                     
                    <!-- Navigation -->
         
        </ul>        
          </div>  <!-- End container -->    
         </header> <!-- End header --> 
         
        </div> <!-- End headerWrapper -->
         
        <div id="wt_containerWrapper" class="clearfix">
         <div id="wt_containerWrapp" class="clearfix">
            <section id="wt_section_home" class="wt_section_area">
        
                 
         <div id="wt_home_content">
                <div class="container">
                   <div class="row">
                          <div class="wt-row-container"><div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid " >
         <div class="vc_col-sm-12 vc_hidden-md vc_hidden-sm vc_hidden-xs wpb_column vc_column_container">
          <div class="wt_wpb_wrapper clearfix" >
           <div id="wt_spacer_sc-56694" class="wt_spacer_sc wt_clearboth" style="height:130px; line-height:130px;"></div>
          </div>
         </div> 
        </div></div><div class="wt-row-container"><div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid " >
         <div class="vc_col-sm-12 wpb_column vc_column_container">
          <div class="wt_wpb_wrapper clearfix" >
           
          </div>
         </div> 
        </div></div><div class="wt-row-container wt-row-centered"><div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid " ><div class="container"><div class="row">
         <div class="vc_col-sm-12 vc_col-lg-7 vc_col-md-7 wpb_column vc_column_container">
          <div class="wt_wpb_wrapper clearfix" >
           
         <div class="wpb_raw_code wpb_content_element wpb_raw_html">
          <div class="wpb_wrapper">
           <h1>REGISTER NOW FOR</h1>
        
          </div> 
         </div> 
         <div class="wpb_single_image wpb_content_element vc_align_left">
          <div class="wpb_wrapper">
           
           <div class="vc_single_image-wrapper   vc_box_border_grey"><img width="763" height="134" src="http://thenutritioncoachuk.com/24FitClub/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/24FIT_CLUB-landscape.png" class="vc_single_image-img attachment-large" alt="24FIT_CLUB landscape" /></div>
          </div> 
         </div> 
         <div class="wpb_raw_code wpb_content_element wpb_raw_html">
          <div class="wpb_wrapper">
           <h1>COMPLETELY FREE</h1>
        
          </div> 
         </div> 
         <div class="wpb_raw_code wpb_content_element wpb_raw_html">
          <div class="wpb_wrapper">
           <h2>4 WEEK CHALLENGE </h2>
          </div> 
         </div> 
         <div class="wpb_raw_code wpb_content_element wpb_raw_html">
          <div class="wpb_wrapper">
           <h3>MONDAY, WEDNESDAY & FRIDAY, 6:30AM & 7PM </h3>
          </div> 
         </div> 
          </div>
         </div> 
        
         <div class="vc_col-sm-12 vc_col-lg-5 vc_col-md-5 wpb_column vc_column_container">
          <div class="wt_wpb_wrapper clearfix" >
           
         <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
          <div class="wpb_wrapper">
           <div role="form" class="wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f1125-o1" lang="en-US" dir="ltr">
        <div class="screen-reader-response"></div>
        <form name="" action="insert.php" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate="novalidate">
        <div style="display: none;">
        <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="1125" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="4.2" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="en_US" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f1125-o1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_wpnonce" value="46263cb454" />
        </div>
        <h4>Sign up to find out when your next 4 week challenge is</h4>
        <p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap yourname"><input type="text" name="yourname" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Full Name" /></span> </p>
        <p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap youremail"><input type="email" name="youremail" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Enter your email" /></span> </p>
        <p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap yoursubject"><input type="text" name="yoursubject" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Phone number" /></span></p>
        <p class="wt_form_text">We will never spam you, or sell your email to third parties. All fields are required</p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Register Now" class="thankyou.php" /></p>
        <div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div></form></div>
        
          </div> 
         </div> 
          </div>
         </div> 
        </div></div></div></div><div class="wt-row-container"><div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid " >
         <div class="vc_col-sm-12 vc_hidden-md vc_hidden-sm vc_hidden-xs wpb_column vc_column_container">
          <div class="wt_wpb_wrapper clearfix" >
           <div id="wt_spacer_sc-37804" class="wt_spacer_sc wt_clearboth" style="height:140px; line-height:140px;"></div>
          </div>
         </div> 
        </div></div><div class="wt-row-container"><div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid " >
         <div class="vc_col-sm-12 wpb_column vc_column_container">
          <div class="wt_wpb_wrapper clearfix" >
           
          </div>
         </div> 
        </div></div>
                        </div>
                 </div>
         </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: Sounds like two questions.

Answer (score 0):

In response to resizing images based on browser size. Make sure IMG is sized in relative units rather than pixel dimensions. The most common relative solution is to set the max-width of the image at 100%:

```
<img src="http://thenutritioncoachuk.com/24FitClub/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/logo24.png" alt="DESCRIPTION" />

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

This is the easiest way to accomplish what you're looking for. Although, there are other ways. I can't see any grey bar?

Comment: Grey bar only appears when the files is in html form and the monitor is bigger than the image
http://i.imgur.com/GSqn7pe.jpg

Comment: It looks like the Background Image needs to stretch to fill the content area. Look at this - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: the image is stretched to fill the area. you can see the whole image breifly then the grey bar appears over it

Comment: Have you got a live version to view?